# WP8 MessageBox with FlowDirection right-to-left

Tags: windows-phone-8, messagebox, right-to-left

my question is simple : is there a way to make a message box with a flow direction right to left ? We are currently doing a project where this would be a nice to have. But title and text are all left to right.

We are using MessageBox.Show and Guide.BeginShowMessageBox.

Thanks,

michal

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but you might want to have a look at CustomMessageBox in the Windows Phone Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need message box? Maybe you'll create some custom control like message box and add efects?

Comment: sure I can do that, but the question was if I can make MessageBox accept FlowDirection :)

Comment: A native Message box = no. CustomMessageBox in the Windows Phone Toolkit = maybe, but i don't think so, because i have tried it, and it just simulates the native message box only allows to change the contents.
So i think the best way will be to create native like custom control and do whatever you like